# Using function as argument to another function

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a function which takes another function and evaluate it with a shared independent variable like so:

```
T2[Tf_] = Integrate[Exp[t] Tf[t], t]
```

But if I try to call like this:

```
T2[HeavisideTheta[t - 3]]
```

It writes the integral out, but doesn't perform it, and there is an extra `[t]`:

```
T2[HeavisideTheta[t - 3]]

\[Integral]E^t HeavisideTheta[-3 + t][t] \[DifferentialD]t
```

The correct answer is of course:

```
Integrate[Exp[t] HeavisideTheta[t - 3], t]

(-E^3 + E^t) HeavisideTheta[-3 + t]
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a [pure function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html):

```
T2[HeavisideTheta[# - 3] &]
(*    (-E^3 + E^t) HeavisideTheta[-3 + t]    *)
```